How can I format a list to print each element on a separate line in python script?
# open the sample file used

file = open('logFile.txt')

# read the content of the file opened

content = file.readlines()

print(content[287:330])


#need to print separate line for 287 line to 330.

i am expecting separate line.
Kindly help me.

print(*content[287:330], sep="\n")

I have another Doubt... Kindly help me. i am getting output is vertical format. But i need horizontal format. I Tried but not yet.                                                             with open('logFile.txt') as file:
content = file.readlines()
for line in content[52:74]:
print(line, end='')
for line in content[287:330]:
print(line, end='')                                                                                                                                                     This is my script. Kindly help me
